# Apache ProxyPass returns 400 Bad Request with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, https, kubernetes, ingress

I have an Apache server in front of a web application server (AEM) that proxies requests to another application server (Magento). When I'm using this on localhost with HTTP everything is fine, but after deploying entire stack to Kubernetes in Google Cloud HTTPS is added on top of it and browser shows 400 Bad Request.

Configuration looks like this:

```
Define magento_host https://my-magento.cloud

ProxyPass "/magento/graphql" "${magento_host}/graphql"
ProxyPassReverse "/magento/graphql" "${magento_host}/graphql"
```

The endpoint is also available via HTTP, but when I use it then response is 308 Permanent Redirect.

Is there a way to fix that in apache config?

Entire file is here: https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-cif-components/blob/core-cif-components-reactor-0.9.0/dispatcher/conf/magento-proxy.conf